# Math.js is not working on jsfiddle

Tags: jsfiddle, math.js

I'm new to jsfiddle so it's probably something obvious but I cannot get the CDN for Math.js to work.

Here is my html code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/1.6.0/math.js"></script>
```

and here is my javascript

```
alert(Math.sqrt(-4));
```

When I run the code it gives me NaN which is what it should give if Math.js has not loaded because Math.js is supposed to support imaginary numbers. Any help is appreciated

Here's the URL for the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/noahthefuzzy/95mxb0dL/2/

And here is the website for [Math.js](http://mathjs.org/)

Comment: What's the URL of your jsFiddle?

Comment: I've added it in the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use lowercase `math` instead of uppercase `Math`:

```
alert(math.sqrt(-4)); // 2i
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [Math.sqrt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt) returns NaN for negative values.  Change your javascript to,

`alert(Math.sqrt(4))`;

And you'll see Math.js is loading fine.

Comment: Math.js is supposed to support imaginary numbers